# Include classes circular in order to keep backwards compatibility in C++

Tags: c++

I have two classes, called `A` and `B`. Class `B` contains a copy of class `A`:

```
class A
{
    //Some definitions
    double func_A(double val);
}
class B
{
    A local_class_A;

    template <typename T>
    T func_B(T val);
}
```

The reason for the inclusion of class `A` in `B` is that `A` contains values needed in `B`.

Now function `func_B()` is a generalized version of `func_A()`, while the latter only takes doubles, the former is a template-dependent function. Else both are doing exactly the same calculations.
Now I would like to put both functions into one function, in order to reduce the amount of possible errors. In theory that can be done by only calling `func_B()` in the future, but I still would like to keep `func_A()`, in order not to break legacy code. Thus one idea would be to call `func_B()` inside of `func_A()`, and therefore redirecting everything to only one function. But that would be a circular loop, after `A` then includes `B`, which in turn includes `A` again, which I would like to avoid.

So, in short: I have two functions in two classes, doing exactly the same. I would like to point both functions to one code line, but I would still retain both functions. I can not include one function into the other due to backwards compatibility and circular dependencies. What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: If you factored out the body of this function into a separate function, how would there be a circular dependency, since the factored-out function knows nothing of A or B?

Comment: You mean, to write a separate function `T func_C()`, which then in turn is called from both `func_B` and `func_A`?

Comment: Yes.  That's what I would have thought would be one obvious way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **template specialization**:

Using templates, we write code once and use it for any data type including user defined data types. If a problem arises in which we want a different code for a particular data type, then it is possible in C++ to get a special behavior for a particular data type. This is called template specialization.

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A(){ cout << "A()\n"; }
    T add(T x, T y);
};

template <typename T>
T A<T>::add(T x, T y)
{
    return x+y;
}

// Specialized class
template <>
class A <char>
{
public:
    A() { cout << "Special A()\n"; }
    char add(char x, char y);
};

char A<char>::add(char x, char y)
{
    int i = x-'0';
    int j = y-'0';
    return i+j;
}
```